# Jquery only works on one certain page. Shows no errors on the other ones, but does not work

Tags: php, jquery

**The idea:**

- The script and php is placed in one php-file so it should be easy to insert into different pages.

**What works:**

- The script works fine on the front page.

**What does not work:**

- The script does not work on any other pages.
- There are no errors appearing when the script does not work.

**What I have tried:**

- Moving the script to the footer, header, start of body. Nothing worked.
- Drop the script, and do the effects with CSS (did not work, it's complicated for CSS)

**Script + php:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#lear_forside').hover(function() {
    $('#bestill_forside').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#bestill_forside').css('color', 'black');
    $('#lear_forside img').attr('src', '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h.png');
    $('#bestill_forside img').attr('src', '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_v_ny.png');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout
    $('#bestill_forside').css('background-color', 'black');
    $('#bestill_forside').css('color', '#99cc66');
    $('#lear_forside img').attr('src', '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h_ny.png');
    $('#bestill_forside img').attr('src', '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_v.png');
  });
});
</script>

<div id="bestill_lear_forside" class="row">
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-custom" data-toggle="modal">
        <div id="bestill_forside" class="col-sm-6 svart">
                <div class="pull-right vertical-center half-content-wrapper" style="width: 100%;margin-right: 80px">
                        <img class="pull-left" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_v.png">
                        <span class="pull-right bestill_forside_venstre">Bestill foredrag!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </a>
        <a href="http://sookvisuals.com/dev/innbokskontroll/laer-innbokskontroll/" target="_self">
        <div id="lear_forside" class="col-sm-6 hvit">
            <div class="pull-left vertical-center half-content-wrapper" style="width: 100%;margin-left: 80px">
                        <img class="pull-right" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h_ny.png">
                        <span class="bestill_forside_hoyre">Lær innbokskontroll!</span>
                </div>
         </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I guess that there are something missing, or somethings is overwriting the script. What should I do? Should I insert the script an other place?

I include the following in my header:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you including the jQuery core in every page? Are you seeing errors in the console?

Comment: Does the function `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` actually echo out the stylesheet directory or return it?

Comment: *"Script does not work"* - Lordie, I love those titles; it really grabbed me and explained what the question is about; *not*.

Comment: I am sorry hearing that you had problems reading the code. Yes, the function `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` echo the stylesheet directory. So in this case, it get the URL of the image. Yes @Fred, I am aware of that. I was thinking about writing "Script does not work on all pages exept for the front page." In 1 minute I am going to edit the post. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Using a descriptive title related to the problem, will indeed attract more people and in turn, get a better response.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I have updated the post, but I have no idea if it makes the post any better.

Answer (score 0):

There is one error on page:-

```
$('#lear_forside img').attr('src', '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h.png');
```

Has been changed to

```
$('#lear_forside img').attr('src', "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h.png");
```

You have used Single quotes for bloginfo, there were four places, Try the Script below and re run the Code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#lear_forside').hover(function() {
    $('#bestill_forside').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#bestill_forside').css('color', 'black');
    $('#lear_forside img').attr('src', "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h.png");
    $('#bestill_forside img').attr('src', "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_v_ny.png");
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout
    $('#bestill_forside').css('background-color', 'black');
    $('#bestill_forside').css('color', '#99cc66');
    $('#lear_forside img').attr('src', "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_h_ny.png");
    $('#bestill_forside img').attr('src', "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/ikoner/pil_v.png");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by replacing all the ID's with Classes.